# Need google autocomplete suggestions directly in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am trying to make an application.
I need google suggestions of random queries (a phrases).

How do I get the autocomplete suggestions directly to my javascript page (i am using jquery).

I tried this: `http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=YOURQUERY`

But it download a `f.txt` file. With an array of suggestions.

I need the content of the file in a variable of javascript. I have basic knowledge of AJAX.

Thank you for any help.